# How to solve errors Awk and Top in Solaris

Tags: bash, awk, solaris

Hi i lanched the script in Solaris and it gave me "top: illegal option -- 2
Top version 3.8beta1
Usage: top [-ISTabcinqu] [-d x] [-s x] [-o field] [-U username] [number]
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

I dont' understand how to solve it.

The code is

```
CPU_USAGE=$(top -b -n 2 -p 1 | fgrep "Cpu(s)" | tail -1 | awk -F'id,' -v prefix="$prefix" '{ split($1, vs, ","); v=vs[length(vs)]; sub("%", "", v); printf "%s%.1f%%\n", prefix, 100 - v }')
```

Comment: Going forward, when you have multiple separate problems (e.g. 1 with `top` and another with `awk`) it's best to try to solve them (and if you can't then ask for help with them) separately rather than bundling all your problems together and trying to solve them all (or ask for help with them all) at once..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have 2 error messages:

1. from top: `top: illegal option -- 2 Top version 3.8beta1 Usage: top [-ISTabcinqu] [-d x] [-s x] [-o field] [-U username] [number]`
2. from awk: `awk: syntax error near line 1 awk: bailing out near line 1`

The `awk` one is because you're calling old, broken awk (/usr/bin/awk on Solaris). Don't do that as it's, well, old and broken and should never be used by anyone for any purpose. On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk (or xpg6) instead. (if someone advises you to use `nawk` - don't as it's older and further from POSIX compliance than the xpg versions).

For the `top` one - read the man page for whatever version of `top` you're calling I guess and maybe look for a `/usr/xpg4/bin` version of `top` too.

Comment: *maybe look for a `/usr/xpg4/bin` version of `top` too*  There won't be one.  The `xpg*` directories are for POSIX-compliant utilities.  `top` is a Linux tool.  Nevermind that [`top` screws up free memory calculuations](https://www.unix.com/solaris/136240-free-memory-top-prstat-command.html).